# PHP magic constants not working

Tags: php, magic-constants

When I input this PHP code, the magic constant `_LINE_` just gets output literally.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

echo "This is line"._LINE_."blah";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
 This is line_LINE_
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two underscores. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

two underscores before and after :

```
__LINE__
```

Comment: No , Just programmers ,No outsiders

Comment: I go on #freenode on IRC to discuss about programmaing